# Creating a Circle object Error .Java

Tags: java

Getting an error when compiling my main and the error is coming from my class file.
The object of this is to create a program that requires a user to create a circle then return to the user the area, diameter and circumference.

```
java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args)   {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    double circumference;
    double radius = 5.7;
    double pi = 3.14159;
    double area = 0;

    Circle circleobject = new Circle();

    //Get radius
    System.out.println("What is the circle's Radius?");
    radius = keyboard.nextDouble();

    if (radius == 0.0) {
        radius = 5.7;
    }

    System.out.println("Creating a circle object.");
    //Creating the class object

    Circle circle = new Circle();

    System.out.println("Your circle's area:  " + Circle.getArea());
    System.out.println("Your circle's Diameter " + Circle.getDiameter());
    System.out.println("Your circle's Circumference " + Circle.getCircumference());
}
```

**This is my class file**

```
public class Circle {
    double circumference;
    double radius = 0.0;
    double pi = 3.14159;
    double area = 0;

    public void setRadius() {
        radius = radius;
    }

    public void radius() {
        radius = 0.0;
    }

    public void getArea(double area) {
        area = 0;
        area = pi * radius * radius;
    }

    public void getDiameter(double diameter) {
        diameter = radius * 2;
    }

    public void getCircumference(double circumference) {
        circumference = 2 * pi * radius;
    }   
}
```

**This is the error that shows up when I compile the main.**

```
Driver.java:38: error: method getCircumference in class Circle cannot be applied to given types;
System.out.println("Your circle's Circumference " + Circle.getCircumference());
                                                        ^
  required: double
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
  1 error
```

Comment: Yours metods should be `setArea`, `setDidameter`, ..., not `getArea`... `gets` methods have to return something...

Comment: Nope, it should be `getArea`, `getDiameter`, etc. since this value are computed from initial parameter `radius` and `pi` constant. There should not be `diameter`, `area` and `circumference` attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method

```
public void getCircumference(double circumference)
{

circumference = 2 * pi * radius;
}
```

should be rewritten as:

```
public double getCircumference() {
    return 2 * pi * radius;
}
```

Using Java conventions, you should use getters and setters in the following way:

```
private xxx myAttribute;
// Here you can check if passed values are correct, for example if you expect a negative value or not.
public void setMyAttribute(xxx a) {
   this.myAttribute=a;
}

// It just returns the current value
public xxx getMyAttribute() {
   return myAttribute;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should replace this method:

```
public void getCircumference(double circumference) {
    circumference = 2 * pi * radius;
}
```

By this :

```
public double getCircumference() {
    return 2.0 * pi * radius;
}
```

I.e. It should not take any parameters, and return the circumference as the result value.

**Edit**

You should modify your `getArea` and `getDiameter` as well :

```
public double getArea() {
    return pi * radius * radius;
}

public double getDiameter() {
    return radius * 2;
}
```

**Edit2**

If I may say so, you should modify your code further. First, your `Circle` class should look like this:

- `PI` is a static constant (the same for every instance of Circle)
- You should add a constructor with a `radius` parameter, thus you can instantiate a new `Circle` providing the `radius`
- Diameter, area and circomference does not need attributes in the class. They are directly computed from `radius` and `PI`
- add a `getRadius()` method to provide public access to the `radius` value.

There is an example of what I would do:

```
public class Circle {

    private static final double PI = 3.14159;

    private double radius = 0.0;

    public Circle(double radius){
        setRadius(radius);
    }

    public void setRadius(double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    public double getRadius() {
        return radius;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return PI * radius * radius;
    }

    public double getDiameter() {
        return 2.0 * radius;
    }

    public double getCircumference() {
        circumference = 2.0 * PI * radius;
    }
}
```

Thus, your main program would look like this:

```
java.util.Scanner;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args)   {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        double radius;

        Circle circleobject = new Circle(radius);

        //Get radius
        System.out.println("What is the circle's Radius?");
        radius = keyboard.nextDouble();

        if (radius == 0.0) {
            radius = 5.7;
        }

        System.out.println("Creating a circle object.");
        //Creating the object

        Circle circle = new Circle(radius);

        System.out.println("Your circle's area:  " + circle.getArea());
        System.out.println("Your circle's Diameter " + circle.getDiameter());
        System.out.println("Your circle's Circumference " + circle.getCircumference());
    }
}
```

I removed some useless variables (`circumference`, `pi` and `area`), modified the way you instantiate the `Circle` object (using the new constructor) and modify the call to `getArea()`, `getDiameter()`, `getCircumference()` (you called them as static methods, but you need to call them on the instanciation `circle` since they are not static methods).

I suggest you to take a look at [Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) and [Returning a Value from a Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)  Oracle's articles, and more generally to the whole [Classes and Objects chapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html).